# Connect-SPOService Only When Necessary

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm writing an administrative script for my SharePoint Online instance, and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent unnecessary connections to the SPO Service.

For example, I have 5 functions that each executive an administrative function. Each one obviously requires that I have successfully connected to the SPO Service before the rest can be run.

If I open the script with the intention of running more than one of the functions, I don't want to have to connect more than once.

Is there a way for me to check whether the connection is already established before I connect again?

Example Code:

```
 function Admin-Function_A{
    Write-Host "Connecting to SharePoint Online" -ForegroundColor White

    try {
        Connect-Function
        Write-Host "Successfully connected to SharePoint Online." -ForegroundColor Green
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Connection to SharePoint Online failed." -ForegroundColor Red 
    }

}

function Connect-Function{
    # Import the module 
    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking
    # Load credential 
    $credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter admin account password" -UserName $adminUsername
    Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $credential 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little i saw about SPOService connections, once you open it, it stays connected until you close it, using Disconnect-SPOService or when the session is closed.
You could add all your functions to the same script and call the Connect-Function before doing your work.

Did i understood it correctly?
Anything let me know

Comment: That... makes a lot of sense. Man, what a stupid question in hindsight. This is less a technical challenge and more about planning a bit better :)

Comment: hahaha there's no thing such as stupid questions. The most obvious things are the ones we take for granted. Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is all in theory as I do not have access to SPO

```
function Test-SPOConnected {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    Write-Verbose 'Testing Connection to SharePoint Online'
    try {
        # Choose a command that you know should return something if you are connected, 
        # preferably only a small amount of objects, or error otherwise
        # Based off documentation I've choosen Get-SPOSite 
        # however there could be a better option
        $results = Get-SPOSite -ErrorAction Stop

        If ($results) {
            Write-Verbose 'Successfully connected to SharePoint Online.' 
            $true
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning 'Nothing returned.  Not connected to SharePoint Online.'
            $false
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning 'Connection to SharePoint Online failed.' 
        $false
    }
}
```

Then in other code/functions you can check connection by using an if statement

```
if (!Test-SPOConnected) {
    Connect-Function
}
# do SPO stuff
```